# Android Retrofit 2 Simple XML don't keep order

Tags: android, retrofit2, simple-framework

How to use `@Order` when has alias name ?

```
@Root
@Order(elements={"?", "?"})
class Test{

  @Element(name = "T_NAME")
  private String name;
  @Element(name = "T_AGE")
  private String age;
}
```

I've tried to use this way:

```
@Order(elements={"name", "age"})
```

And

```
@Order(elements={"T_NAME", "T_AGE"})
```

But don't work for me!

I really need keep right order.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of `@Order(elements={"T_NAME", "T_AGE"})` worked for me.  May be there was a bug that is fixed now?